# Listview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a listview in my form. Everytime the user enters an item code, it will be listed in the listview. What I want to do is when the user entered the cash, and after the system computes for the change, I want to deduct the items bought in the database record. As of now, I have this code:

```
    Do While tmp <= ListView1.Items.Count

        Do While a <= ds.Tables("ItemInfo").Rows.Count               

            it = ListView1.Items(tmp - 1).SubItems(0).Text
            qt = ListView1.Items(tmp - 1).SubItems(3).Text


            If it = ds.Tables("ItemInfo").Rows(a).Item("ItemCode") Then
                'MsgBox(ds.Tables("ItemInfo").Rows(a).Item("ItemCode"))
                ct = ds.Tables("ItemInfo").Rows(a).Item("Qty")
                nw = Convert.ToInt32(ct) - Convert.ToInt32(qt)
                MsgBox(nw)
                con1.Open()
                mycommand = New SqlCommand("update ItemInfo set Qty='" & nw & "' where ItemCode='" & it & "'", con1)
                mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con1.Close()

                'Exit Do

                'Else


            End If
            a = a + 1
        Loop

        tmp = tmp + 1

    Loop
```

But the problem is it didn't deduct all the items inside the listview. It is always the first line in the listview whos is being deducted in the database. I dont know if the problem is in the looping or what. Thankyou in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to stackOverFlow heres the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) must read

Comment: How about how to loop through all the listview items? Because in my code, it's always the first line of listview which is being read..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `foreach` to read all the items from the `ListView`

```
For Each i As ListViewItem In listView1.Items

Next
```